# How can I use a variable outside a function, im looking to get the documentdata() variable into the answer buttons

Tags: swift, xcode

Since I call the getdata() in the viewDidLoad function I cant get the variable documentdata out. Im trying to use the documentdata's data for the button. I know I need a return type for the get data as well, but I cant seem to get that. TLDR: im trying to get the value documentdata into another a whole other function. Thank you in advance for anyone who responded.

```
    import UIKit
   import Firebase
  import FirebaseFirestore
 class QuizViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var answerButtonTwo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var answerButtonOne: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var answerButtonThree: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var answerButtonFour: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var displayAnswerChoice: UILabel!
var isrun = false
var documentdata:[String:Any] = ["":""]
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupElements()
    getData()

   }


func setupElements(){
    answerButtonOne.setTitle("", for:.normal)
    answerButtonTwo.setTitle("", for:.normal)
    answerButtonThree.setTitle("", for:.normal)
    answerButtonFour.setTitle("", for:.normal)

    questionLabel.text = ""
    displayAnswerChoice.text = ""
}
func getData() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("quizs").document("basketballQuiz").getDocument { (document,error) in

               if error == nil{
                   print("cant get data")

               }
               if document != nil && document!.exists{
               let documentdata = document!.data()
               self.questionLabel.text = documentdata?["Question"] as? String
               self.answerButtonOne.setTitle(documentdata?["Answer1"] as? String, for:.normal)
               self.answerButtonTwo.setTitle(documentdata?["Answer2"] as? String, for:.normal)
               self.answerButtonThree.setTitle(documentdata?["Answer3"] as? String, for:.normal)
               self.answerButtonFour.setTitle(documentdata?["Answer4"] as? String, for:.normal)

               }

    }

   }



  @IBAction func AnswerOneTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let rightAnswer:Int = documentdata["correctAnswer"] as! Int
    if (rightAnswer == 1){
        displayAnswerChoice.text = "Correct"
        displayAnswerChoice.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Green")
    }

}
@IBAction func AnswerTwoTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let rightAnswer:Int = documentdata["correctAnswer"] as! Int
    if (rightAnswer == 2){
        displayAnswerChoice.text = "Correct"
        displayAnswerChoice.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Green")
    }

}
@IBAction func AnswerThreeTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let rightAnswer:Int = documentdata["correctAnswer"] as! Int
    if (rightAnswer == 3){
        displayAnswerChoice.text = "Correct"
        displayAnswerChoice.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Green")
    }
}
@IBAction func AnswerFourTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let rightAnswer:Int = documentdata["correctAnswer"] as! Int
    if (rightAnswer == 4){
        displayAnswerChoice.text = "Correct"
    }
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the received `documentdata` to the property `documentdata`

```
if let documentdata = document?.data() {
    self.documentdata = documentdata
    self.questionLabel.text = documentdata["Question"] as? String
    self.answerButtonOne.setTitle(documentdata["Answer1"] as? String, for:.normal)
    self.answerButtonTwo.setTitle(documentdata["Answer2"] as? String, for:.normal)
    self.answerButtonThree.setTitle(documentdata["Answer3"] as? String, for:.normal)
    self.answerButtonFour.setTitle(documentdata["Answer4"] as? String, for:.normal)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats it, it worked. Im just a little curious why this worked. Thank you again

Comment: The local variable `documentdata` and the property with the same name on the top level are two different objects. The former is available only in the scope of the `if` expression, the latter is available in the entire class.